# Angular make one request to api per some time?

Tags: angular, api, caching, request

I have angular directive and services. That directive is showing or hiding elements from component - depends on api answer. If user have permission to some element it allows to show that, in another way it is hiding element. But I want to make this type of request only one time per 10min, then store answer and for another element use cached information? How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a service which makes the request on behalf of these components. In the service you can use a BehaviorSubject.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  showItem: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(true);

  constructor(private http: Http){
     setInterval(() => this.myRequest(), 1000000)
  }

  myRequest(){
    this.http.get('enpoint')
      .subscribe(data => this.showItem.next(/* resolve data to true or false*/))
  }
}
```

then in you component you inject this service and you can subscribe to the behavior subject

```
@Component({
   template: `<my-component *ngIf="myService.showItem | async"></my-component>`
})
export class AComponent {
  constructor(public myService: MyService){ }
}
```

any of your components can now subscribe like this

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [shareReplay](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/sharereplay.html) operator on an observable. It will replay the last X number of items from an observable, and there is a time parameter for how long it should cache values.